# How to run tests using selenium grid from Jenkins on different remote servers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, selenium-grid

We have Jenkins server hosted in Linux server, and we want to trigger our selenium tests from Jenkins to different remote desktops (Windows) using selenium grid (Here, Jenkins, hub, and node all three are in different machines).

Note: We aren't allowed to host Selenium hub in the same machine where we have Jenkins or install any Selenium Grid plugin in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote driver. Here is simple example

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://<your_windows_IP_ADDR>:4444/wd/hub', options=options)
```

It will be in your code, you will run Selenium Server(Grid) on your Windows device. Then you can configure any setup after that.

Comment: What about the Jenkins side?

Comment: it is a broad topic. Which language did you use to write your framework? what is your runeer? depend on that answers, you will create a Jenkins job to execute command that trigger the tests. For each language and library it may changes.

Answer (score 0):

hi we have same requirement any update on how to achive this.From Jenkins how can we trigger suite on remote machine

Comment: Either use comments option to ask your queries, or create a new question and ask about your specific issue. Do not ask a question in the answer section.